# Code generator upgrades my code to T4

Tags: c#, entity-framework, t4, objectcontext

I am working in an old project which use edmx files version 3. Client have upgraded entity framework to 6, but they didn't changed in the edmx.

Now I need to add a tabel to the model, when I am doing that the code generator upgrades generated code to T4. and I am getting 1640 errors because the new code doesn't have EntityState and Context.AddToAdmin ......

I am totally lost, and I don't know if these information is enough to understand my problem. Just ask if you need further information.

Is there anyway to force visual studio to use Legacy ObjectContext and not to upgrade code to T4

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Was there a reason to upgrade to EF 6?

Comment: No, there was no reason for that.

Comment: Then, I'd be tempted to revert to EF 3 and avoid the problem entirely. Whenever you upgrade through several major versions you're likely to have to make more than a few changes to your code base. In my experience, it's not worth the hassle unless there is a specific reason to do so.

Comment: Please help me understand the problem. Who is reponsible to generate the code? On other words If I revert to EF3 will I be able to add tables into the model without any problem? Visual studio will not use T4 in generating the code?